# Visibility:hidden does not work in Firefox but works in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

This HTML/CSS code works fine in Chrome but is not working in Firefox. I tried to use

```
border:none; / border-style:none;
```

but it didn't seem to solve the problem.

Please see this JSFiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/1su2e0L7/3/)

Result in Chrome:
[image: chrome]

Result in Firefox:
[image: firefox]

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Please fix link to JSFiddle

Comment: post a valid jsfiddle Link

Comment: trying .......... :D
Update: link is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, below, is a solution to resolve the problem you have:

```
<th style="border-top-color: transparent;border-bottom-color:
transparent;">&nbsp;</th>
```

Check up this JSFiddler : [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/1su2e0L7/16/)

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Might something like this be of use? Should work in FF but it's kinda specific so would have to be adapted for another layout.

```
th:nth-of-type(4), td:nth-of-type(4){
    border:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/79bbxcaw/

Comment: This works but the other solution was easier to implement, thanks for poiting this out.